# Mongo query using filter not fetching exact result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongo table contains contains **collection 'Shops'** and data like the below:

```
{
    "ShopId" : 9999,
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "productId" : "1234",
            "productName" : "abcd",
        }, 
        {
            "productId" : "5678",
            "productName" : "abc",

        },
         {
            "productId" : "2345",
            "productName" : "def",

        }

    ],
}
```

There will be several shops in the table having a list of products.

**Requirement:**

I want to fetch the records having **shopId=9999** and **products matches the string abc**

**My query**

```
model.Shops.aggregate([{$match:{"ShopId":9999}},{$project:{products:{$filter:{input:'$products',cond: {'productName':/abc/ }}}}}])
```

**Problem:**

It is fetching the `productname:def`with the other data that matches `productname:abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use regex search with the `$filter` operator. The only way to achieve this is to unwind `products`, filter document and then re-group them in an array

```
model.Shops.aggregate([
   {
      $match:{
         "ShopId":9999
      }
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$products"
   },
   {
      $match:{
         "products.productName":/abc/
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         products:{
            $push:{
               "productName":"$products.productName",
               "productId":"$products.productId"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{
   "_id":null,
   "products":[
      {
         "productName":"abcd",
         "productId":"1234"
      },
      {
         "productName":"abc",
         "productId":"5678"
      }
   ]
}
```

to use it with a variable, declare your regex like this:

```
var regex: /abc/;
```

and then use it directly in the query

```
   $match:{
         "products.productName": regex
      }
```

Comment: The query executing fine.  But i have one more doubt.. If i have to place a common variable for match instead of 'abc' . What should i place between                 '/ /'. Is it /searchValue/  or /+searchValue+/

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked on mongoshell for me, and your code was giving error to me, that Missing 'as' parameter to $filter.

```
db.Shops.aggregate([
{$match:{"ShopId":9999}},
{$project:{
    products:{$filter:{input:'$products',as:"product",cond: { $eq: [ "$$product.productName", "abc" ] }}}
    }}
])
```